# Lipschitz of the minimum curve of a convex function of two variables

Tags: convex-optimization

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function in two real variables.   Assume that $f$ is strictly convex by which I mean $f(x,y) - c(|x|^2 + |y|^2)$ is convex for some $c>0$.

Assume for each $x$ there is a unique $w(x)$ such that
$$ g(x): = min_y f(x,y) = f(x,w(x))$$

I would like to know if there are reasonable conditions under which $w$ is Lipschitz in $x$?

For context, the following remark of Kiselman [1,p11] shows that $w$ is actually $C^1$ if $f$ is smooth.   For observe for each $x$ that $w(x)$ is the unique solution to the equation  $f_y(x,w(x)) = 0$.  The Jacobian of this system is the Hessian of $f$ which is positive definite, so invertible.  Thus by the implicit function theorem $w$ is $C^1$.

[1] Kiselman, \emph{Singularities of Plurisubharmonic functions}, Complex Potential Theory pp 273-323

PS: I would also like to know if the function $w(x)$ or the curve $\{x,w(x)\}$ has a name.

Comment: First, I found that w(x) is called the "argmin" function.

Second, I have been able to prove essentially what I want, namely that the function w(x) is Lipschitz almost everywhere.   The argument is rather long so I will not put it here, but I expect it to appear in a forthcoming paper so will reference it when it appears.